# JQuery Scroll controls opacity of a Nav to fade in, how to stop Nav fading out on reverse scroll?

Tags: jquery, css

I am in need of help with some jquery. 
I have a fixed nav at the top of the page thats opacity is set to 0 on page load.
When the page is scrolled down the nav fades in using:

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
$('#nav').css({
        'opacity': 0+(scrollPos/800)
    });
});
```

How can I make it so when the page is scrolled back up it doesn't fade back out?

I have tried doing this with an if statement but my jquery isn't too hot.

Thanks in advance. Edd Neal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 200){
             $('#nav').fadeIn(1000);   
        }
    });
});
```

With the css:

```
#nav{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

A working [JSFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/pxJ9h/).

Using the `fadeIn()` is better than manually changing css because jquery takes care of cross browser css issues automatically. For example, the `opacity` for IE is `alpha(opacity=50)`

Answer (score 3):

Use this: ([woking jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Z8M/1/))

```
function EasyPeasyParallax() {
    scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#nav').css({
            'opacity': 0+(Math.min(scrollPos/800,1))
        });
};

$(function(){
    $('body').bind('mousewheel',EasyPeasyParallax);
});
```

Note: I've used mousewheel event however you can detect the scroll in any way you'd like. also note `Math.min()` usage so the value of opacity will not exceed 1

Another note: use `.stop().animate()` instead of `.css()` for a nicer looking fade effect [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5Z8M/2/).